# Casting Math.Pow to float

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, pow

I'm trying to get a Math.Pow to cast to type float but VS2013 is telling me that I "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'.

I thought I was doing the cast as follows:

```
private void COMBO_AWG_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float d = 0.0f;
    int awg = int.Parse(COMBO_AWG.Text);
    //MessageBox.Show(awg.ToString());
    d = 0.127 * (92 * ((float)Math.Pow(36, awg) / 39));

    TB_awg2mm.Text = d.ToString();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *are* casting it to `float`, but you are multiplying that result with a `double`, resulting in a `double`.

Any literal which is not an integer and is not suffixed with `f` or `F` is treated as a `double`.

To fix this:

```
d = 0.127F * (92 * ((float)Math.Pow(36, awg) / 39));
```

Notice the `F` after `0.127`.

Answer (score 5):

Your casting to `float` works all the way until you muliply with `0.127`, which is a `double` value. All the `int` values will implicitly be converted to `float` to do the calculations. The final multiplcation with a `double` value makes the entire expression be of the type `double`.

The CPU does all floating poing math internally using `double`, so there is no point in using `float` in earlier steps in the calculation if you need to do a cast anyway. Use `double` values all the way (for best precision), and cast the final result:

```
d = (float)(0.127 * (92.0 * (Math.Pow(36.0, awg) / 39.0)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the number `0.127`, the compiler will interpret as a double, hence the result of the whole expression will result in a double value.

Fix it like this:

```
  d = 0.127f * (92.0f * ((float)Math.Pow(36.0f, awg) / 39.0f));
```

Appending `f` to a number makes the compiler interpret it as `float`.

*EDIT:*
For `Math.Pow` no overload for `float` exists, so you have to cast the result.